# js Date changes on october 10th (BST)

Tags: javascript, date, utc

Why does JS Date object change toUTCString on October 10th?

```
new Date('2017-10-9').toUTCString()
"Sun, 08 Oct 2017 23:00:00 GMT"



new Date('2017-10-10').toUTCString()
"Tue, 10 Oct 2017 00:00:00 GMT"
```

I am writing these in the UK. BST ends on October 29th. What is going on?!

Comment: Since you're not using a proper date format, parsing using the Date constructor is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example the date is parsed as local date, and in the second as UTC date. To parse the first date as UTC too, add a `0` before `9`.

```js
console.log(new Date('2017-10-09').toUTCString()); // Mon, 09 Oct 2017 00:00:00 GMT
```

Inconsistencies in date parsing like that are why you should always pass a date in ISO-8601 format to the `Date` constructor. You can also use a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: I think I might cry

Comment: @dafyddPrys https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder662/65251662.jpg

Comment: "*Inconsistencies in date parsing*" are why you shouldn't use the built-in parser at all! ;-)